# Javascript not working or call not working

Tags: javascript

I have a function that works when I'm testing in house but, it does not work when I test it at home.  The function creates a random string and it's being called as soon as I load the form.  I appears that everything works except the function.  I'm not sure why that would be.  Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function randomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 3;
    var randomstring = '';
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    document.getElementById('UniqueId').value = randomstring + hours + minutes + seconds;
}
</script>
```

Comment: add the code to your question...

Comment: This is probably unanswerable without some sample code

Comment: *Check* (this is vague with no code) that any `src` attributes in your `<script />` tags resolve correctly, or for any features you're using your browser at home doesn't support.

Comment: Are you sure the form is in the DOM when you call the function? When you test it on a local connection it might load fast enough, but when you test it on a slower (internet) connection ... it might be the form is not yet loaded in the DOM

Comment: I think the problem might be in line 17. Seriously, how do you expect anyone to help you without even showing a single line of code?

Comment: What are the different browsers you use? Anyway the code you posted is OK with FireFox 14.0.1. Also, we don't see _how_ `randomString()` is called, we just have the function, and maybe the problem is in the calling (as you suggested yourself in the post's title)...

Comment: This is the call:  <body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in' onLoad="randomString()">

Comment: I tried it in Firefox at home but I'm not sure what version of Firefox it is.

Comment: Your going to need to post the url of the online-not-working version

Comment: Here is the url:http://64.124.162.184/Monitoring_new1/Form.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you place this script inside the `head` tag, it is possible that you execute it before the rest of the html is loaded. This means, there is no such element with id `UniqueId` loaded yet and so it cannot be found. Try calling it after the html document is fully loaded.

```
yourFunction = function() { ...code... }
window.onload = yourFunction
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var randomString = function() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 3;
    var randomstring = '';
    var currentTime = new Date();
      var hours = currentTime.getHours();
      var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
      var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
      for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
      }
      document.getElementById('UniqueId').value = randomstring + hours + minutes + seconds;
  }

  window.onload = randomString;
</script>
```

Tested on Firefox 6 and IE 8 on Windows XP and Chrome 21, Firefox 14 on Mac OS X 10.8. It works.

Comment: I've tried placing the script inside of a head tag and the call works in IE but, still doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: Updated my answer with tested code. If you are a fan of Firefox, use Firebug to check for errors and for debugging.